# How do I change a variable from inside a SwiftUI view?

Tags: swift, variables, swiftui

I am trying to detect whether a SwiftUI `ForEach` returns any content:

```
struct FullListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var runningData: RunningData
    @ObservedObject private var Categories = CategoriesStruct()
    private var showNoContentMessage = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        Toggle(isOn: self.$runningData.showSavedOnly){
                            Text ("Show Saved Only")
                        }
                        FilterOptionsView(Categories: Categories)
                    }
                    Section {
                        ForEach (ConditionsList) { ConditionInfo in
                            if (!self.runningData.showSavedOnly || ConditionInfo.isSaved) && (self.Categories.dict[ConditionInfo.category]! || self.Categories.allCategoriesFalse) {
                                showNoContentMessage = false
                                ListElementView(ConditionInfo: ConditionInfo, isItSaved: ConditionInfo.isSaved)
                            }
                        }
                        if self.showNoContentMessage {
                            Text("No matching conditions")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Conditions"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the `ForEach` section, an if statement checks whether or not to display a `ListElementView` for a specific `ConditionInfo` struct of information from `ConditionsList`.  I am trying to make the program display the `Text(“No matching conditions”)` if no `ListElementView` views are displayed.  I was trying to do this by having the `showNoContentMessage` variable default to `true`, but be changed to `false`, if the `if (!self.runngingData...` statement ever returns true.  However, whenever I try to add a `self.showNoContentMessage = false` or a `showNoContentMessage = false` in the aforementioned if statement I get the error: `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`.  How do I edit this variable from within the if statement, or is there I much better way to see if any `ListElementView` views were displayed.  I have tried using functions, passing `showNoContentMessage` variable into `ListElementView` and editing it in there, and using `.onAppear()`, and they have all either not worked or given me different error messages.

Comment: Do this filtering in view model instead of view, and view on check if empty show message else show list.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
private var showNoContentMessage = true
```

to

```
@State private var showNoContentMessage = true
```